# Specifying further type constraints in Scala

Tags: scala, types, traits

I often want to specify a further type constraint in Scala. Here is a simplified example of something I've been trying to do recently:

```scala
trait Foo[K] {
    def apply(key: K): Int

    trait ByID[E <: HasID] where K <: ID[E] {
      def apply(key: E) = Foo.this.apply(key.id)
    }
}
```

Of course the syntax there doesn't work, but how can I achieve this? I want it to infer `E` without asking for it, by extracting it from the type parameter of `ID[...]` when `K` is an `ID`. When `K` is not an `ID`, the `ByID` class should not be available.

Comment: WHICH "class should not be available"? If `Foo` is defined for `K`, then `Foo.ByID` will have to be defined as well. If you mean that `Foo` should not be available when `K` is not an `ID`, then it it is trivial: `trait Foo[E, K <: ID[E <: HasID]] ... `

Comment: I would like the trait, `ByID`, to be available only for certain values of `K`. `Foo` should be available for all `K`.

Comment: make two `Foo`s.